# Select field that is not in a table but from alphanumeric data

Tags: sql, alphanumeric

So I have 2 tables test1 and test2, they both contain columns: id,type,number, I want to select all the number from table test1 that are NOT in table test2, I know this would work;

```
SELECT test1.number,test2.number
FROM test1 LEFT JOIN test2 ON test1.number=test2.number
WHERE test2.number is null;
```

It returns what I was looking for when number column is entirely numeric but happens to be new numbers in new tables are like:

```
test1.number
MFP773773
**MFP874747** 
MFP099290 
MFP763636

test2.number
HBM366363
**HBM874747**
HBM773383
HBM092827
```

Then, how can I do the very same thing but only with the numeric part of "number" like in the second row where number is the same but letters are not, they way that they return different numbers no matter the characters before the numbers,please help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you want to compare the two tables with the numbers in both the coulmns?? in your question you mentioned second row where number is the same but letters are not, can you show me which values you mean by that??

Comment: Are there always 3 letters?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a userdefined function which can extract the numbers. try it out and see.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
    (@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @intAlpha INT
    SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
    BEGIN
    WHILE @intAlpha > 0
    BEGIN
    SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
    SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
    END
    END
    RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
    END
    GO

/* Run the UDF with different test values */
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric('') AS 'EmptyString';
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric('asdf1234a1s2d3f4@@@') AS 'asdf1234a1s2d3f4@@@';
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric('123456') AS '123456';
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric('asdf') AS 'asdf';
SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric(NULL) AS 'NULL';
GO
```